# How to access BinaryFormatter from .NETStandard,Version=v1.7

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I desperately need `BinaryFormatter` to make my application compatible with .NET Framework 4.5.

I know it was impossible to have it in previous versions of NET Core. However I see `BinaryFormatter` is planned for v1.7 release, which is currently in preview version.

`BinaryFormatter` is part of `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters` package/namespace.

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters/src/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.csproj#L57

How can I install nightly build of this package to make my code work?

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is very picky about assembly versioning I would not recommend you use it for any form of cross machine IPC or persisted storage. You will save your safe headaches in the future if you can use a different serialization method.

Comment: In my case serialized objects are meant to be cache entries and won't be shared between different runtimes. They can also be easily recreated. I can't use different method of serialization because it's 3rd party API I'm serializing.

Comment: Caches and intra-machine IPC is a fine use case for BinaryFormatter. I just wanted to give you a heads up if you were not aware and not using one of those two cases.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you would install nightly. If that functionality is not in the .NET Core framework, but you still want your application to use .NET Framework 4.5 namespaces, you could use compiler directive

```
#if net45
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;  
public class BinaryFormatSerializer : ISerializer
{
    public string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
        string binData = serializer.Serialize(obj);

        return new BinaryFormatter(binData).Format();
    }
}
#else // Below you would put whatever logic 
      // to not use 4.5 framework whenever 
      // BinaryFormatter is added to core
```

If you just want to run your .NET Core app on .NET Framework, you can do it by changing adding/changing the moniker in the “frameworks” section of your JSON config file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not easily. [The latest packages on the .Net Core MyGet feed](https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/dotnet-core) still don't contain `BinaryFormatter`.